# Resolve n+1 issue when querying model stored in pivot table attribute

Tags: laravel

I have three models - `service`, `item` and `environment`.

There is a belongstomany() relationship between `service` and `item`.  The pivot table also includes an attribute column for `environment_id`.

When listing the items in a service on the service show page, for example, I also want to include the environment for that item in that context.  There is a `get_env_name()` method in a helpers file for that.

```
function get_env_name($id)
{
$name = \App\Environment::findOrFail($id)->name;

return $name;
}
```

However, this results in a new query for each item listed on the page.

Is there a better way to achieve this?

Some business logic: an item can be in a different environment (dev, test, QA, etc) depending on the service.  For example, server-01 can fulfil a QA role in Service A but a UAT role in Service B.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a custom query to get all the fields needed.

I imagine it would look something like this:

```
DB::table('pivot_table')->where('pivot_table.service_id', $id)->join('items', 'items.id', 'pivot_table.item_id')->join('environments', 'environments.id', 'pivot_table.environment_id')->select('pivot_table.service_id', 'pivot_table.item_id', 'pivot_table.environment_id', 'environments.name')->get()
```

You can add to the select whatever fields you would need from the respective tables.